# SSRS RDL Reports Report Scheduling

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I am working on application where reports are scheduled using Web Application build on asp.net C# language [.Net 4.5 framework] . This Application uses a Drop-down to take report parameters  a category  and a Email Address which is saved in Database.When some user wants a report for particular category  then he select category and report is generated using saved database parameters and this report automatically emailed to that email address using web application.
Report is generated using ReportViewer   ReportViewer.ServerReport.Render(); to convert into excel sheet. Report viewer itself is hidden from users.ReportViewer only used to genrate excel sheet.
Problem is if we have 50 mails then application keep running for 5 Hours which is very frustrating.I have heard about ssrs scheduled reports , but how can i set parameters using Web Application GUI also I need a one click send button on Web Application.If the user log out then it is scheduled in database and reports are genrated in queue.
Please guide me with correct approach. I hope i am able to make every thing clear.
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330071/can-i-send-ssrs-custom-subscription-e-mails/20330200#20330200

Comment: Thank's @DanAndrews it is really help full can you please tell me where to find these scheduled reports on server and can user logout after this.

Comment: Manage report and from there "subscriptions"  I'm confused by your second question, please attempt and let me know if you have any problems.