# Trigger an SSRS Report from ASP.Net without user intervention

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services

I'd like to be able to fire off an SSRS Report from an ASP.Net application without pulling it up in the application and having to print it from there to a specified printer.  This seems like it would be a highly desired feature, but I'm having trouble finding any good solutions online.  Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: for programmatically creating subscriptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330071/can-i-send-ssrs-custom-subscription-e-mails/20330200#20330200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a Web Application standpoint, in modern prowsers, I don't believe you can specify a printer, and you certainly cannot "auto-start" printing.  Reporting services used to have the ability to print unattended with an MS browser plugin, but that was removed a number of years ago as it's now considered a security risk.

The best you can do is "one-click" print, that is programmatically render the report using the Report Execution service from the ReportService.asmx web service and initiate a programmatic solution to print the rendered report.

Unfortunately, printing an SSRS report automatically is quite involved. You can read about [**How to Print Reports Programmatically**](http://printssrsreport.blogspot.com/) here.

Comment: Interesting... I think I saw the link but couldn't believe there wasn't a simpler way.  Thanks, though.

Comment: well that blog is from Sep 2011 - there may well be a better, more up-to-date, approach, but honestly I haven't needed to research it so... :)

Answer (score 2):

rFirst you will need to set up the report to render from an execution snapshot. You should find this under the reports property tab, execute, select the "Render this report from a report execution snapshot" radio button.

Next you will need to set up a subscription for whom you want it delivered to. Under the subscriptions tab, add new subscription, enter the e-mail information, etc. Under "Subscription Processing Options" select "when the report content is refreshed".

Now you need to be able to trigger a new snapshot programmatically. Fortunately, the reports service exposes a web service for this purpose. Add a service reference to:

http:// your_report_server:your_port/ReportServer/ReportService.asmx

Once you add the reference then you simply need to call the UpdateReportExecutionSnapshot method to cause you report to execute and mail out to your subscribers.

A simple c# command line app to this might look like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // The first argument should be the full report path
        // and name. It is passed directly to the Ssrs web service

        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Full report name must be the first parameter");
        }


        // create the endpoint

        ReportingServiceSoapClient ssrs = new ReportingServiceSoapClient();

        // Update the snapshot

        ssrs.UpdateReportExecutionSnapshot(null,args[0]);
     }
```

For the report name, you will need to specify the full report name including any sub folders you have. So if you have your reports say organized by division you would have to specify all the parent folders for example:

/DivisionName/DailyReports/SalesReport

Comment: Interesting... Good information.  I'll look into to the web service.  I see that I neglected to mention that I wanted the report to go directly to a specified printer.  Do you know if that is an option?

Comment: Not sure, there is not an option for that in the version we are using.  Could be there in a later version. However, you can have it go to a network share instead of e-mail. You could probably throw a windows service together to pick that up and shove to specific printer, assuming someone else has not already written something to do that.

Comment: Okay.  I've though about that.  With both these answers, it looks like I'm back to creating a mini-project to accomplish the task.