# SSRS Report to run based on an event

Tags: events, reporting-services, schedule

Here is the scenario the user wants...
The ETL is usually completed at 5 AM and a row is inserted in a table upon successful load.
Starting at 5 AM the SSRS report should look for that row to be inserted, say every 30 seconds.
When it sees a row is inserted and the SSRS report should run which in turn sends an email to the users specified in the subscription.

Is there any way to achieve this without SQL -RD?
Please give me a direction as I am new to MSBI.

Regards,
Chakrapani M

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330071/can-i-send-ssrs-custom-subscription-e-mails/20330200#20330200

Answer (score 0):

It's not an ideal solution, but if you're running Enterprise edition, you could set up a data driven subscription to check for the inserted row, and if it's present, return the list of email addresses - use this returned value to populate the "TO:" field in the data driven subscription.  If no data is present, no email addresses would be returned, and the subscription would simply "fail".

Alternatively, if you have access to do so, just find the job that the subscription creates on the SSRS SQL host, and alter it to add the necessary conditional logic to only run the subscription when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Use a SSIS package with 3 tasks:

1. SQL Task - Single Row Result set - Check if data based on last run date scenario and then update last-run-date
2. SQL Task - On success of task 1 run "Windows File Share" SSRS report (say export as PDF or Excel format)
3. EMAIL Task - On success of task 2 Add file as an attachment and send

Deploy and add the package to a SQL Server job, scheduled for 30 seconds.

Alternatively put the delay (schedule) in the package. I.e. use a For Loop Container (with an optional loop end count) and dump the 3 tasks into it with an additional delay task scenario on failure of task 1 and a exit loop early on success of task 3. Remember to set the MaximumErrorCount of the For Loop to 0 and the each individual task in the loop besides the first task FailPackageOnError property to True in order to avoid the intentional error to call the delay if no result from the ETL.