# SSRS Data Driven Subscriptions: save file to location AND send email

Tags: reporting-services, subscriptions

I want SSRS to produce a file to a specific location and send emails out to a list of recipients.  The need to archive a series of reports is something everyone is interested in, we want to avoid sending out a lot of attachments, and the notification of a newly produced report adds value as well.  Unfortunately, it seems I can only accomplish one or the other of these things with subscriptions.

While looking around the interwebs for the solution the common refrain is that I can accomplish one or the other, but not both.  Is it a requirement that I create two subscriptions?

Comment: If you make your comment into an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: I did it, hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Short Answer***

Using one subscription you cannot do that.

***Workaround***

If you are sure you don't want to use two subscriptions alternatively you can customize programmatically your subscription class, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330071/can-i-send-ssrs-custom-subscription-e-mails) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36009/Programmatically-Playing-With-SSRS-Subscriptions).

Also I recommend you check SSIS, using it you could send emails to your users when SSRS generate the file to the location.

Let me know if this helps.